# VSTO 4.0 Excel 2007 Add-in causing Memory leaks on Windows 7

Tags: vsto, excel-2007

We have a VSTO 4.0 Add-in for Excel 2007 that seems to have issues with Memory leaks, but only certain documents and only on Windows 7.  The behavior is similar to the LCID proxy issue that was supposedly remedied in VSTO 4.  The memory spikes at about 1.2 to 1.5 GB then throws an OutOfMemory Exception.  This only seems to happen when I try to open certain documents when runing on Windows 7.  If I open the same documents in XP, the memory certain goes high but I do not get an exception.  Basically, I get various exceptions and never in the same place twice:

----- Source: System.Windows.Forms -----

System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

at System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromRectangle(Rectangle rect)

at System.Windows.Forms.Screen.GetWorkingArea(Rectangle rect)

at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsUtils.ConstrainToScreenWorkingAreaBounds(Rectangle bounds)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.GetDropDownBounds(Rectangle suggestedBounds)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.SetBoundsCore(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBounds(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Size(Size value)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.AdjustSize()

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownMenu.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(LayoutEventArgs args)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.PerformLayout(IArrangedElement affectedElement, String affectedProperty)

at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutTransaction.DoLayout(IArrangedElement elementToLayout, IArrangedElement elementCausingLayout, String property)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.InvalidateItemLayout(String affectedProperty, Boolean invalidatePainting)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.InvalidateItemLayout(String affectedProperty)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.OnRightToLeftChanged(EventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownItem.OnRightToLeftChanged(EventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.OnOwnerChanged(EventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnOwnerChanged(EventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.SetOwner(ToolStrip newOwner)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.SetOwner(ToolStripItem item)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.Add(ToolStripItem value)

at Hcg.Stinger.Report.ShadowRangeTree.ShadowRangeNodeEventBehavior.AddDynamicLabelMenu() in C:\Serenity6.x\Source\Hcg\Stinger\Report\ShadowRangeTree\ShadowRangeNodeEventBehavior.cs:line 135

Here's another one:

----- Source: System.Windows.Forms -----

System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripManager.ProcessShortcut(Message& m, Keys shortcut)

at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripManager.ProcessCmdKey(Message& m, Keys keyData)

at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ProcessCmdKey(Message& msg, Keys keyData)

at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessCmdKey(Message& msg, Keys keyData)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessCmdKey(Message& msg, Keys keyData)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessCmdKey(Message& msg, Keys keyData)

at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.ProcessCmdKey(Message& msg, Keys keyData)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)

at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)

---

When I save the documents as stand alone docs and do not open them using the VSTO Add-in, it is able to open them with minimal memory.  When I use the add in to open them, that's when things spin up and crash.

Any help or pointers as to why Windows 7 has these issues would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Erick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured out the the application was creating thousands of ToolStripMenuItems for context menus on TreeNodes.  Once I made those shared, it took care of the memory issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "Once I made those shared..."??? I have also memory problems and ContextMenuStrip-Controls that are containing various ToolStripMenuItems. But I don't know how to make them "shared". Can you help?

Comment: @jreichert what I mean by shared is to simply add them to the tree menucontext. I had been creating individual ones for every single node. I simply use rules to decide which ones show for which node.